# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'graphviz_layout' with networkx 1.11

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I'm trying to draw some DAGs using networkx 1.11 but I'm facing some errors, here's the test:

```
import networkx as nx

print nx.__version__

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1,level=1)
G.add_node(2,level=2)
G.add_node(3,level=2)
G.add_node(4,level=3)

G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(2,4)

import pylab as plt
nx.draw_graphviz(G, node_size=1600, cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                 node_color=range(len(G)),
                 prog='dot')
plt.show()
```

And here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\sources\personal\python\framework\stackoverflow\test_dfs.py", line 69, in <module>
    prog='dot')
  File "d:\virtual_envs\py2711\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 984, in draw_graphviz
    pos = nx.drawing.graphviz_layout(G, prog)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'graphviz_layout'
```

I'm using python 2.7.11 x64, networkx 1.11 and I've installed [graphviz-2.38](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php) having `dot` available in PATH. What am I missing?

Once it works, how could i draw the graph with nodes which:

- Use white background color
- Have labels inside
- Have directed arrows
- Are arranged nicely either automatically or manually

Something similar to the below image

[image]

As you can see in that image, nodes are aligned really nicely

Comment: Use either `nx.graphviz_layout` or `nx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout`.

Comment: @ValentinLorentz When trying `nx.graphviz_layout` I'll get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'graphviz_layout'` but using `nx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout` kinda works. Although neither  `nx.graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot') nor nx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G)` are showing anything. If you could provide a mcve example of this I could validate your answer, thanks!

Comment: How do you get the graph to have that theme, with the labels in the nodes?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The package layout has changed in later versions of networkx. You can import the graphivz_layout function explicitly.

```
import networkx as nx
import pylab as plt
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout


G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1,level=1)
G.add_node(2,level=2)
G.add_node(3,level=2)
G.add_node(4,level=3)

G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(2,4)

nx.draw(G, pos=graphviz_layout(G), node_size=1600, cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
        node_color=range(len(G)),
        prog='dot')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Graphviz can do what you want.  Thanks for the vote but changing the question after the answer is given isn't so nice http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296489/when-is-it-ok-to-extend-a-question-with-another-question-after-initial-answers

Comment: You should award the bounty for answering your question as originally posed.  I can answer your follow-up question but it is different than your original question.

Comment: A minor change @Aric:  When using `graphviz_layout` explicitly, the `prog=` argument needs to be passed to `graphviz_layout`, not `.draw`.  If not `"neato"` is assumed (per the docs).