# Network graph is not visually optimized in NetworkX

Tags: python, graph, visualization, networkx

I'm new to using [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io) so I might be doing something wrong.  I'm trying to create simple graphs using data scraped from [wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_programming_languages).  Below is an example of a simple graph I constructed using the spring_layout option.  Is this the kind of output to be expected?  I was thinking it would re-arrange the points to try to avoid crossing lines so that it looks visually simpler.  It doesn't seem to have tried to avoid crossings at all.

Also, I wanted more of a flow diagram going from left to right like [this](http://www-03.ibm.com/ibm/history/ibm100/files/S608123Y18657C60/us__en_us__ibm100__fortran__computer_language_evolution.pdf) (each point has a year value) (or vertically) but this [doesn't seem to be possible in NetworkX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801880/how-to-use-the-pos-argument-in-networkx-to-create-a-flowchart-style-graph).  Can anyone confirm that?  A linear flow diagram would seem to me to be a common need.

[image]

Data in this example:

```
selected_nodes = [96, 64, 163, 132, 166, 138, 108, 141, 238, 50, 58, 60, 61, 223]

selected_edges = [
    (50, 58),
    (61, 64),
    (60, 64),
    (58, 96),
    (108, 132),
    (96, 141),
    (138, 163),
    (141, 163),
    (64, 166),
    (163, 223),
    (132, 238),
    (96, 238),
    (166, 238),
    (223, 238)
]

text_labels = {
    50: u'ALGOL 58 (IAL)',
    58: u'ALGOL 60',
    60: u'COMIT (implementation)',
    61: u'FORTRAN IV',
    64: u'SNOBOL',
    96: u'ALGOL 68 (UNESCO/IFIP standard)',
    108: u'SETL',
    132: u'ABC',
    138: u'Modula',
    141: u'Mesa',
    163: u'Modula-2',
    166: u'Icon (implementation)',
    223: u'Modula-3',
    238: u'Python'
}
```

Script code

```
# This visualisation creates a network graph 
# with the spring layout

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

G = nx.DiGraph() # Create an empty Graph

G.add_nodes_from(selected_nodes)
G.add_edges_from(selected_edges)

plt.figure(1,figsize=(15,15))
#nx.draw(G, node_color='c', edge_color='k', with_labels=True)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

plt.figure(1,figsize=(15,15))

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, arrows=True)
#nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels)

for p, values in pos.iteritems():
    x, y = values
    plt.text(x+0.04, y+0.02, s=text_labels[p], horizontalalignment='center')

plt.savefig('lang_predecessors.pdf')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You might try a layout other than spring_layout, and check the questions regarding networkx layouts for options that are more sophisticated.

Comment: Thanks.  I did try other layouts ('circular_layout', 'random_layout', 'shell_layout', 'spring_layout', 'spectral_layout', 'fruchterman_reingold_layout') but couldn't find a nice simple linear or hierarchical layout.  To be honest I'm lacking a good simple explanation of the layout options.  Or some examples.  The documentation does not seem to have much.

Comment: [graphviz_layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092390/network-graph-is-not-visually-optimized-in-networkx) by [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) could possibly be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

```
The graphviz dot layout has a hierarchical layout.  If you install pygraphviz you can use it like this

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import to_agraph

selected_nodes = [96, 64, 163, 132, 166, 138, 108, 141, 238, 50, 58, 60, 61, 223]

selected_edges = [
    (50, 58),
    (61, 64),
    (60, 64),
    (58, 96),
    (108, 132),
    (96, 141),
    (138, 163),
    (141, 163),
    (64, 166),
    (163, 223),
    (132, 238),
    (96, 238),
    (166, 238),
    (223, 238)
]

text_labels = {
    50: u'ALGOL 58 (IAL)',
    58: u'ALGOL 60',
    60: u'COMIT (implementation)',
    61: u'FORTRAN IV',
    64: u'SNOBOL',
    96: u'ALGOL 68 (UNESCO/IFIP standard)',
    108: u'SETL',
    132: u'ABC',
    138: u'Modula',
    141: u'Mesa',
    163: u'Modula-2',
    166: u'Icon (implementation)',
    223: u'Modula-3',
    238: u'Python'
}
G = nx.DiGraph() # Create an empty Graph

for k,v in text_labels.items():
    G.add_node(k,label=v)
G.add_edges_from(selected_edges)

A = to_agraph(G)

A.draw('lang_predecessors.png', prog='dot')
```

[image]