# Drawing network with nodes and edges in python

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

```
g=nx.DiGraph(directed=True)
g.add_nodes_from(o)
for j in range (len(o)):
   for i in range(len(ixx)):
      g.add_edge(ixx[i],o[j-1])
   g.add_edge(o[j-1],WIN[0], weight=10)   
nx.draw(g,with_labels=True)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

This was the code of graph. 
ixx is the input node, WIN is the single output node and o is the hidden node.

An example network looks like this. (This is what I am getting when I run my code)
[Numbers from 1 to ...26 are hidden nodes. 27 is output node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzssY.png)

But, I want to plot it like: input nodes on left side, hidden in the middle and output node on right side. Like exactly how the Neural network looks.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: You should have a look at the `pos` argument. Also, [this previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801880/how-to-use-the-pos-argument-in-networkx-to-create-a-flowchart-style-graph) might help.

Comment: This is no "Write code for me" forum. You have to step up and provide your code to us if you got specific problems you have researched (google/SO) and can not solve yourself. Read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) , provide code respecting [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and your exception / expectation that do not get met by your code and I am sure SO will help you out. Coding to your Specs does not fit into SO Q&A format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a demo of how that could be done:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import sample, seed 

seed(0)
G=nx.dodecahedral_graph()

# splitting the graph to the sets of nodes
samples = sample(G.nodes,2)
output_set = set(samples[:1])
input_set = set(samples[1:2])
hidden_set = set(G.nodes) - output_set - input_set

# a function for shifting node positions
def make_spring_pos(nodes,shift):
  return { node:(pos[0]+shift,pos[1]) for node,pos in nx.spring_layout(G.subgraph(nodes)).items() }

# shifting node positions for different sets
input_pos= make_spring_pos(input_set, shift=0)
hidden_pos= make_spring_pos(hidden_set, shift=3)
output_pos= make_spring_pos(output_set, shift=6)

# merging positions back
all_pos = {}
for pos in [input_pos,hidden_pos,output_pos]:
  all_pos.update(pos)

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=all_pos)

plt.show()
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you, that was so useful.