# Cannot use graphviz in Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: python, graphviz, google-cloud-datalab

[This](http://data.gdeltproject.org/blog/google-cloud-datalab-demos/Getting%20Started%20with%20GDELT%20%2B%20Google%20Cloud%20Datalab%20-%20Simple%20Network%20Visualizations.html) is a tutorial about visualizing network diagrams using Google Cloud Datalab.

Everything worked perfectly (needs to change "gcp.bigquery" to "datalab.bigquery" in [25]) until:

```
In [35]:

%%bash
/usr/bin/yes | apt-get install graphviz
pip install --upgrade graphviz
/usr/bin/yes | pip uninstall pyparsing
pip install -Iv https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyparsing/pyparsing-1.5.7.tar.gz
pip install --upgrade pydot
```

Once I uninstalled `pyparsing`, the pip command cannot work and the next 2 lines cannot be executed correctly.

If I ignore the lines related to `pyparsing`, just install/upgrade `graphviz` and `pydot`, an error will occur at this line in "In [67]:" :

```
pos=nx.graphviz_layout(gmax, prog='circo')
```

> `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'graphviz_layout'`

I don't think it is a `pyparsing` matter. Maybe the `graphviz` version is the point, since this tutorial was written about 2 years ago.

Any idea about it?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'graphviz\_layout' with networkx 1.11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39411102/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-graphviz-layout-with-networkx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The network graph displayed correctly after I changed

```
pos=nx.graphviz_layout(gmax, prog='circo')
```

to

```
pos=nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(gmax, prog='circo')
```

based on [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279733/what-could-cause-networkx-pygraphviz-to-work-fine-alone-but-not-together). This required `pydotplus` so I also updated one of the cells with `%%bash`. I ran

```
%%bash
apt-get update
apt-get install -y graphviz
pip install pydot
pip install graphviz
pip install pydotplus
```

instead of

```
%%bash
/usr/bin/yes | apt-get install graphviz
pip install --upgrade graphviz
/usr/bin/yes | pip uninstall pyparsing
pip install -Iv https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyparsing/pyparsing-1.5.7.tar.gz
pip install --upgrade pydot
```

I hope this helps!